# call javascript link on pageload

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have a link on my page, and  when I click on this it opens a login popup. This works after click on the link.

I want that on page load. I have wasted lots of time on this but nothing works.

`<a id="onestepcheckout-login-link" href="javascript:void(0);"><?php echo $this->__('Already registered? Click here to login.'); ?></a>`

This code I am using. Right now is working onclick but I want this on page load.
Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just did a simple one.This will help you.Just check it http://jsfiddle.net/ArLKy/8/

Answer (score 0):

There's the `onload` event of the `<body>` tag:

```
<body onload="document.getElementById('onestepcheckout-login-link').onclick()">
```

Here's a cleaner method:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function()
{
  OpenLoginBox();
});
```